# Tic Tac Toe game in Java FX

Tags: java, beginner, tic-tac-toe

I have programmed a Tic Tac Toe game in JavaFX and would appreciate feedback. Have I gone wrong anywhere?

One issue I found and fixed was that I encountered a "Effectively final" error when I tried to use variables declared outside the lambdas in the lambdas. I resolved it by changing some of them to instance variables. I'm not sure if that is the right approach.

Are there any areas that don't seem right or are clunky? Should I have had more than one class?  Where could I improve?

```
package ticTacToe;
 
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 
 
public class TicTacToeApplication extends Application {
    private Button[][] board; //array representation of the game board
    private String player; //player X or O
    private int playerXCount; //counter for the number of turns player X has taken 
    private int playerOCount; //counter for the number of turns player O has taken
    private  Label lbl;
 
    public TicTacToeApplication() {
        board = new Button[3][3];
        player = "X";
        playerXCount = 0;
        playerOCount = 0;
        lbl = new Label("Turn: X" );
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(TicTacToeApplication.class);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        
        lbl.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 40));
        createButtons(grid, lbl);
        
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setTop(lbl);
        layout.setCenter(grid);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        
    }
    
    public void createButtons(GridPane grid, Label lbl){ //create buttons and handle button presses
        
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
            for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
                Button btn = new Button(" ");
                btn.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 40));
                grid.add(btn, col, row);
                board[row][col] = btn;
                
                btn.setOnAction(e -> {
                    
                    if(btn.getText().equals(" ")){
                        btn.setText(player);
                        if(player.equals("X")){
                            player = "O";
                            lbl.setText("Turn: O");
                            playerXCount++; //incement counter after every turn
                            System.out.println("X: "+playerXCount); //ignore: used for debugging
                            System.out.println("O: "+playerOCount); //ignore: used for debugging
                            if(playerXCount % 3 == 0){ //checks for winner if the number of turns completed are in multiples of 3 (i.e. 3, 6, or 9)
                                checkForWinner();
                                System.out.println("Checking for Winner....");//ignore: used for debugging
                            }
                            
 
                        }else {
                            player = "X";
                            lbl.setText("Turn: X");
                            playerOCount++;
                            System.out.println("X: "+playerXCount); //ignore: used for debugging
                            System.out.println("O: "+playerOCount); //ignore: used for debugging
                            if(playerOCount % 3 == 0){//checks for winner if the number of turns completed are in multiples of 3 (i.e. 3, 6, or 9)
                                checkForWinner();
                                System.out.println("Checking for Winner...."); //ignore: used for debugging
                            }
                            
                        }
                        if(playerOCount + playerXCount == 9){ // end game if stalemate reached (max total turns of 9 played) with no winner
                            endgame();
                        }
                    }
                    
                });
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public void checkForWinner(){
        checkRowsForWinner();
        checkColumnsForWinner();
        checkDiagonalLeftForWinner();
        checkDiagonalRightForWinner();
    }
 
    private void checkRowsForWinner() { //go through all three rows to check for winner and end game if symbols are the same on a row
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
            if(board[row][0].getText().equals(board[row][1].getText()) && 
                    board[row][0].getText().equals(board[row][2].getText()) && 
                    //!board[row][0].getText().isBlank()){ // encountered "Cannot find sysmbol" error for isBlank()
                    !board[row][0].getText().equals(" ")){ //to avoid registering three blank buttons in a line as a win 
                endgame();
            }
        }
        
    }
 
    private void checkColumnsForWinner() { //go through all three columns to check for winner and end game if symbols are the same in a column
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
            if(board[0][col].getText().equals(board[1][col].getText()) && 
                    board[0][col].getText().equals(board[2][col].getText()) && 
                    //!board[0][col].getText().isBlank()){ // encountered "Cannot find sysmbol" error for isBlank()
                    !board[0][col].getText().equals(" ")){ //to avoid registering three blank buttons in a line as a win
                endgame();
            }
        }
    }
 
    private boolean checkDiagonalLeftForWinner() {
            if(board[0][0].getText().equals(board[1][1].getText()) && 
                    board[0][0].getText().equals(board[2][2].getText()) && 
                    //!board[0][0].getText().isBlank()){ // encountered "Cannot find sysmbol" error for isBlank()
                    !board[0][0].getText().equals(" ")){ //to avoid registering three blank buttons in a line as a win
                endgame();
            }
        
        return false;
    }
 
    private boolean checkDiagonalRightForWinner() {
            if(board[0][2].getText().equals(board[1][1].getText()) && 
                    board[0][2].getText().equals(board[2][0].getText()) && 
                    //!board[0][2].getText().isBlank()){ // encountered "Cannot find sysmbol" error for isBlank()
                    !board[0][2].getText().equals(" ")){ //to avoid registering three blank buttons in a line as a win
                endgame();
            }
            return false;
        }
    
    private void endgame() {
        lbl.setText("The end!");
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
                board[row][col].setDisable(true); //disable buttons
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for sharing your code!

OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of this is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (amongst others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")

It does not necessarily involve "creating more classes"...

The most critical aspect part in your code is the violation of the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) pattern. You have lots of code, that looks very similar and only differs by *literal values*. This could be extracted to separate methods that get the different values as parameters.